# submit posts by unregistered users in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am newbie in wordpress.
Is it possible to allow unregistered users submit a post and put it in a queue to get confirmed with site admin and when be shown on the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gravity Forms has this ability. Love the plugin, and it works VERY well..

Gravity forms is available here:  http://www.gravityforms.com/

I believe you can use the Personal license to do what you want; but, the developer license has the best goodies.

Comment: I should mention, there's another way.. Allow anyone to register, and make the default permissions as a "Contributor".

Answer (score 0):

The Plugin 'User Submitted Posts' is a cheap & cheerful way to do this:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-submitted-posts/

I use a modified version of this plugin and it works perfectly well.